# HP DL385 Base System Device

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant, server-setup

I have an HP DL385 with two Operon 280 CPUs and 16 GB of RAM running Windows Server 2003 R2 64 bit. Windows device manager show a yellow question mark for the Base System Device. This device is the ILO card, however everything seems to be working with it. Where can I find a driver for the device?

Answer (score 5):

Visit the HP DL385 site [HP Downloads](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DriverDownload.jsp?prodNameId=3288114&lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=428936&taskId=135)

Comment: I found the required files on the HP site.